# How can I arrange this SQL query with codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Here is what i want to do with classic query:

```
$sql=  "SELECT * 
        FROM chat 
        WHERE (GidenId = {$UserId} AND GelenId = {$gelenId} 
           OR (GelenId = {$UserId} AND GidenId = {$gelenId} 
        ORDER BY Id DESC";
```

And here is the way I tried

```
$this->db->where(["GidenId"=>$UserId,"GelenId"=> $gelenId]);
$this->db->or_where(["GelenId"=>$UserId,"GidenId"=> $gelenId]);
$this->db->order_by("Id DESC");
$vr1 = $this->db->get("chat")->result();
```

If I use this way `or_where` is not returning what I want. `or_where`'s way is results in

```
GelenId"=>$UserId or GidenId"=> $gelenId
```

But these two conditions must be fixed.

Comment: ___Small Point___ You _Classic_ query has missing brackets and therefore would not run

Comment: it only shows you what i want to. Then i also know classic way would not run

Comment: Oh right, so you want to write a codeigniter script that does not run?

Comment: show me plase missing brackets

Comment: There are 2 this one `)` and this one `)`

Comment: `WHERE ( ... OR (...` and never closed.